# Odoo 11.0 Inventory module customization problem?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11, inventory

I have added a 'back to draft' option on a customized stock_picking. When back in draft state, if any move is modified and save is called then picking successfully moves to 'ready' state. Issue occurs if a combined move is edited, in this case the save method is not called.

I am looking for a way to override 'Save' so whenever picking is edited in 'draft' state it moves to 'ready' state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved it by overwriting create and write methods on the pre-defined models.

```
# override function create
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    # your code
    res = super(StockPicking, self).create(vals)
    return res

# override function write (write = update)
def write(self, vals):
    # your code
    res = super(StockPicking, self).write(vals)
    return res
```